# How to explain the source of funds transfered to my bank account for a UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am a student intending to apply for a 6-month visitor visa. I have monthly savings of about £200 for the last 6 months, which I mentioned in the application, and it's reflected on my bank account. I am going to apply next month. In the last month my mom transferd about £2,500 from her bank account to mine to support my visit, but I mentioned in the application that “no one is paying for my trip”, because if she only has those £2500+£300 in her bank account so if i say that she is paying for my trip I should then provide her bank statement, which I want to avoid.

What should I do to prove the source of this fund to avoid refusal due to money parking? I have a “bank transfer form” for the transaction and a “debit advice”. Would it be enough to provide them with the application? Is there is any other way?

Comment: You're asking us how to lie to the authorities and get away with it.  Not only are we unlikely to help, this is unlikely to work.

Comment: i am not lieing! i am genuinely intending to visit uk for a week and then return to my country! i only have limited fund! would it be impossible for me to travel!?

Comment: You received funds from your Mum ("*mom transferd about £2,500 from her bank account to mine to support my visit*"), and have misrepresented the source of them ("*I mentioned in the application that “no one is paying for my trip"*").  How is that not lying?

Comment: @ramy_rt You state in your question that you have not yet applied. If this is still the case, based on what you say I’d reconsider whether to apply at all - you’ve already fallen into a likely funds parking refusal which you can’t avoid unless you provide your mum’s bank statement, and even if you do ‘proportionality’ considerations will also come into play. It does not sound like you can afford this trip at the moment and it’s likely UKVI will conclude the same thing.

Comment: i have already booked interview, the bank transfer fund form wouldn’t be enough?

Comment: Not that it really matters, but interview for what? A job? A PLAB test? A master's or ph.d position? British army? So this isn't a vacation, but has another purpose.

Comment: i am an egyptian, i must book an interview for the visa

Answer (score 3):

**You are absolutely going to have to provide evidence to support the source of these funds.**

Frankly you are already describing lying on your immigration form, something that is going to get you a refusal and possibly a ban on further applications. You might claim "My Mom gave me this money for no specific purpose and I decided to use it on this trip" but that's going to be hard to believe.

The transfer into your account already looks suspicious, and without lots of explanation is going to get you a refusal. The trick of putting extra borrowed money temporarily into an account to make it look better is extremely well known, and even if this is not your intention, having financials that look like this will be reason for rejection. Your application will not be the first that the visa officer has seen that looks like this - probably not the first that day.

A 'bank transfer form' and 'debit advice' are not enough. They only prove that you received the money, which your statement already shows. You absolutely need to show that the money originated from your Mom, which means showing her bank statements. Probably helpful would be an affidavit that this money is yours to keep, and not a loan.

Moreover if your Mom has only the money she gave you in her account, then even the statements are not going to help. You would need to include other financial records to show that she can afford to give you this money, and where *she* got the money from. No sensible person gives away all the money they have in the world just so that their son can take a vacation in the UK, and the visa officer will not believe she is doing it.